# Python error while reading MS project .mpp file using mpxj module in Rstudio

Tags: python, ms-project, mpxj

I am trying to read .mpp MS project file using python mpxj but it throwing invalid file format error.Below is code chunk and output error image.please anyone can help on this.ASAP[code in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNRZY.jpg)

[output with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTpEM.jpg)

Comment: Could you attach `test.mpp`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.